# Wrapper in Backbone View cannot be parametrized in order to work with d3.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, d3.js

I have encountered something and I don't understand it. I'm having a Backbone.View - lets say A - and inside of the initialize statement I'm loading another View that is wrapper - lets say B - in which I'm executing some d3js code. However, I'm loading the topview object (app) inside of A so the view with cid = "view1".

```
define([], function(){
   return Backbone.View.extend({
      initialize: function(app, options) {
         this.app = app;
         this.setElement($(this._tmpl()));

         require(['someurl/wrapper'], function(wrapper){
            this.wrapper = new wrapper(app);
         })
    },

    _tmpl: function() {
       return '<div id="d3jsview">'+'</div>';
    }
  });
});
```

And the wrapper looks like this.

```
define([], function() {
   return Backbone.View.extend({
      el: "#d3jsview",
      initialize: function(app, options) {
         this.app = app;
         this.render();
      },

      render: function() {
         var w = 640, h = 480;
         var svg = d3.select(this.el)
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", w)
                .attr("height", h);
      }
   })
})
```

So when I call the wrapper with new wrapper(app) the d3js code is not working. Without it new wrapper() it works. However, I need to access the model inside of app. What am I missing. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting an id, so you should try : `d3.select("#" + this.el)`

Comment: I made a mistake in the code. Actually it states el:"#d3jsview". Thanks. I changed the code.